# Fonts and header

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

In the Meta site, the font-specification is

```
font-family: 'LusitanaRegular',"Palatino Linotype",Palatino,"Hoefler Text","Book Antiqua",Georgia,serif;
```

which contains an error in the first name so it's ignored and one of the Palatinos is substituted.

Fonts are all over the place; some items are Georgia by default; some are Lusitania [it's spelled correctly in the Main site]; some are Arial/Helvetica. And the main title's capital C comes from a different family from the rest of the name, which really, really grates.

Comment: what spelling error? 'LusitanaRegular' is the embedded webfont. The reason for a mix of Georgia and Helvetica/Arial(for tags) is because Lusitana isn't as readable in smaller sizes.

Comment: Hmm. Well, it's not working. It is working in Main.

Comment: what OS/browser ver are you using?

Comment: Firefox 21.0 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems we had a web config error for Meta causing the custom font file not downloading. I didn't catch this error because I have the font installed on my computer as a system font. The fix will be pushed out to live shortly.

Comment: +1 Thanks. And sorry about the misdiagnosis. But it would be nice if Georgia (and Goudy) could be banished so there was only one serif and one sans.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I love Lusitana. I think it's a more elegant serif than Georgia, especially for the design of this site. My concern is that it may not render too well as body font. But, I'll switch the question and answer body text over to it tonight, and see if we get any complaints. In my experience, web fonts just don't render well on Windows, especially at smaller size.

Comment: I've asked a [new question](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/6280/can-we-have-a-font-with-better-italics) about changing the font to improve italics and small-size rendering.